My SO is due a raise, but they refuse to give it to him. How can they handle this?
My boyfriend has worked for his company for over a year. Before that, he had worked for a similar field and had several years of experience in this same field.
He is still yet to receive his yearly raise which is 6 months over due and is now being bypassed and looked over for a promotion that he is more than qualified for and the one who is being considered isn't qualified and a lesser candidate.
My boyfriend works almost seventy percent of all of his days off, Works multiple people's positions and takes on multiple jobs while working when shorthanded, has only been late to work twice in over a year and a half. His only downfall is that he is too nice and non confrontational to verbally address this or to make his concerns known due to not wanting to jeopardize his job.
He has almost a spotless record while in this company's employment, unlike other candidate who is almost always late, calls in, refuses to do more than his own load of work, and calls in. My boyfriend was given reason is because they didn't want to loose such a great employee... Seriously, refusal to promote because that would mean losing your work mule?! With no raise still??
This seems crazy to me and we need to fix this problem and he doesn't want to quit so how can this situation be handled?

Welcome to TWP please take the [tour] and read the [help/dont-ask]

I'm not here to get popular or be known. I just need help knowing what S.O. should do? I live in country and never online so technically might ask couple questions a year if that. Why do I need all this profile stuff and everything else if I literally only have 1 question??

im writing a question in the meantime... be patient and kind... btw, did you use two accounts? one to post this and this one you comment from?

Thanks for fixing the double user situation :) I posted an answer for you to consider. Best of luck!

@DarkCygnus thank you for the edit.

This question is similar to: How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Nobody is owed a salary increase nor are salary increases guaranteed. Have your boyfriend stop working on his off days, if he wants to work for free, that’s on him to stop don’t let it be his boss otherwise he might not like their resolution to that problem. Calling in (sick) is a negative?

@CountryGrandma - Question: Do you work in the same office or company as your SO - or are you hearing all this information 2nd hand

In many companies, you are never due for a raise; you are due to be evaluated for a raise to be given if your performance is good enough and the company is being profitable enough to afford it.

@CountryGrandma, Would you please tell us what "S.O." stand for ? I know your question is about your boyfriend's work. But, I don't know what "S.O." means.

"My boyfriend works almost seventy percent of all of his days off" then those 70% are not days off...

@Job_September_2020 SO stands for Significant Other (i.e. your partner or spouse)

@CountryGrandma This question is focused on the company not giving a raise. You can't do anything about that. The SO needs to make a decision or come here to ask their own question about their own behavior and options.


He is still yet to receive his yearly raise which is 6 months over due

This means that he did not get a raise.  Not all companies give yearly raises.  Some that do, may not in a particular year due to other factors. Most companies, in the US, call them "merit" raises indicating they are not guaranteed, but earned.

My boyfriend works almost seventy percent of all of his days off

Is he paid for working his days off?  If he works a Saturday, is there more money in his next paycheck?

unlike other candidate who is almost always late, calls in, refuses to do more than his own load of work, and calls in

Comparing yourself to others is a losing game.  If one wants a promotion they need to advocate the value they bring to the company to management.  They also need to find out that path to promotion and do those things.
The bottom line is that you do not work there, your boyfriend does.  He may be inaccurate in his description of things.  He may have misunderstood management, you may be misunderstanding him.  There is a lot that can be different from your understanding and reality.
Working overtime is not necessarily a path to promotion.  If your boyfriend is compensated for working his days off, well that is his choice and he is receiving a reward for doing such.
One thing that you have not outlined is the company's path to promotion.  Do you and he understand what are the requirements are to receive a promotion?  Has he done those things?
You have not made the case for this being discrimination, or even that he should be promoted at all.


My boyfriend was given reason is because they didn't want to loose such a great employee! Seriously refusal to promote because that would mean losing your work mule?! With no raise still?? This seems crazy to me and need to fix this problem and he doesn't want to quit so what should he do??

Ok so what we see here is that the company gives great value to your boyfriend and the way they work, and they surely don't want to lose him.
I identify with your way of thinking: if he is so great and valued by the company, who definitely doesn't want to lose him, why not give him a raise?
Time for some advice now:

His only downfall is that he is too nice and non confrontational to verbally address this [the raise that is due] or to make his concerns known due to not wanting to jeopardize his job.

I feel this is the key aspect of what you share with us. As per the state of things it seems that a raise won't be given (or more seriously considered) if your boyfriend doesn't raise this concern. I must say, addressing this situation (professionally of course) is surely not a way to jeopardize your job. He is in his right to ask for it and get an explanation.
Unless your boyfriend stands up and professionally bur firmly raises this issue I fear there will be no raise, and he'll be stuck in the "good, underpaid employee" limbo forever.
Look at it this way. They surely don't want to let your boyfriend go, so if politely reminding of the due raise does not work, looking for another job seems to be the only way out of this loop. If they really value him, they'll give him the due raise.
This company may be taking advantage of the good-will and dedication of your boyfriend, and unless he speaks up things will remain the same.

He's also non-confrontational enough to not challenge management that they are understaffing, and taking his availability for extra work for granted. This isn't just about the lack of a raise - it seems he hasn't set any boundaries with them. Time off is there for a reason - his long term wellbeing (and the wellbeing of your relationship too).
